# Visualforce Table Only Displays Query Results on Update

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm hoping I can get some help with a custom object entry screen. I am trying to use the recipe from michaelforce.org's blog [Snazzy Product Entry Screen](http://www.michaelforce.org/recipeView?id=a0G30000006eVxVEAU) but instead of using it as a product selector on opportunities I want to select a custom object (Site) and associate it with quotes through another custom object (Associated Locations).

Right now I have it functioning where it will show the Associated Locations on a quote but when I go to add Site records it does not display them when I go to the Visualforce page but when I remove a site (using the 'removeFromSelectedSites' class) it shows all available sites correctly.

What am I missing where it is not querying and displaying all available sites when the Visualforce page is rendered the first time around? I can see in the developer environment that there are three SOQL queries when using the tool as is for product selection but only two SOQL queries on the apex I have written.

Thanks in advance for the help! I am by no means a developer but a tool like this would be extremely useful to myself (and I think to others so if you are interested let me know).

Below is the Apex:

```
public with sharing class quoteSiteEntryExtension {

    public Quote theQuote {get;set;}
    public String searchString {get;set;}
    public Associated_Location__c[] selectedSites {get;set;}
    public Site__c[] AvailableSites {get;set;}

    public String toSelect {get; set;}
    public String toUnselect {get; set;}

    public Boolean overLimit {get;set;}

    private Associated_Location__c[] forDeletion = new Associated_Location__c[]{};


    public quoteSiteEntryExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        theQuote = [select Id, Name, AccountId from Quote where Id = :controller.getRecord().Id limit 1];
        selectedSites = [select Id, Quote__c, Site__c, Name, Site__r.Name, Remarks_Special_Instructions__c from Associated_Location__c where Quote__c=:theQuote.Id];
    }

    public void updateAvailableList() {
        String qString = 'select Id, Name, Account__c from Site__c where Account__c= \'' + theQuote.AccountId + '\'';
        if(searchString!=null){
            qString += ' and (Name like \'%' + searchString + '%\')';
        }

        Set<Id> selectedEntries = new Set<Id>();
        for(Associated_Location__c d:selectedSites){
            selectedEntries.add(d.Site__c);
        }

        if(selectedEntries.size()>0){
            String tempFilter = ' and Id not in (';
            for(Id i : selectedEntries){
                tempFilter+= '\'' + (String)i + '\',';
            }
            String extraFilter = tempFilter.substring(0,tempFilter.length()-1);
            extraFilter+= ')';

            qString+= extraFilter;
        }

        qString+= ' order by Name';
        qString+= ' limit 101';

        system.debug('qString:' +qString);        
        AvailableSites = database.query(qString);

        if(AvailableSites.size()==101){
            AvailableSites.remove(100);
            overLimit = true;
        }
        else{
            overLimit=false;
        }       
    }

    public void addToSelectedSites(){
        for(Site__c d : AvailableSites){
            if((String)d.Id==toSelect){
                selectedSites.add(new Associated_Location__c(Quote__c=theQuote.Id, Site__c=d.Id));
                break;
            }
        }

        updateAvailableList();  
    }


    public PageReference removeFromSelectedSites(){
        Integer count = 0;

        for(Associated_Location__c d : selectedSites){
            if((String)d.Site__c==toUnselect){

                if(d.Id!=null)
                    forDeletion.add(d);

                selectedSites.remove(count);
                break;
            }
            count++;
        }

        updateAvailableList();

        return null;
    }

    public PageReference onSave(){
        if(forDeletion.size()>0)
            delete(forDeletion);
        try{
            if(selectedSites.size()>0)
                upsert(selectedSites);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }  

        return new PageReference('/' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'));
    }

    public PageReference onCancel(){

        return new PageReference('/' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'));
    }
}
```

Visualforce Page (sorry about formatting):

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote" extensions="quoteSiteEntryExtension" >

    <apex:sectionHeader Title="Manage {!$ObjectType.Site__c.LabelPlural}" subtitle="{!quote.Name}"/>
    <apex:messages style="color:red"/>


    <apex:form >

        <apex:outputPanel id="mainBody">


<!-- this is the upper table... a.k.a. the "Shopping Cart"-->

            <!-- notice we use a lot of $ObjectType merge fields... I did that because if you have changed the labels of fields or objects it will reflect your own lingo -->
            <apex:pageBlock title="Selected {!$ObjectType.Site__c.LabelPlural}" id="selected">

                <apex:pageblockTable value="{!selectedSites}" var="s">

                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:commandLink value="Remove" action="{!removeFromSelectedSites}" reRender="selected,searchResults" immediate="true">
                            <!-- this param is how we send an argument to the controller, so it knows which row we clicked 'remove' on -->
                            <apex:param value="{!s.Site__c}" assignTo="{!toUnselect}" name="toUnselect"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Site__c.Fields.Name.Label}" value="{!s.Site__r.Name}"/>

                    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Associated_Location__c.Fields.Remarks_Special_Instructions__c.Label}">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!s.Remarks_Special_Instructions__c}" style="width:70px" required="false" />
                    </apex:column>

                </apex:pageblockTable>


                <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!onSave}" value="Save"/>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!onCancel}" value="Cancel" immediate="true"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            </apex:pageBlock>

<!-- this is the lower table: search bar and search results -->

            <apex:pageBlock>

                <apex:outputPanel styleClass="search">
                    Search for {!$ObjectType.Site__c.LabelPlural}:
                </apex:outputPanel>

                <apex:actionRegion renderRegionOnly="false" immediate="true">

                    <apex:actionFunction name="fetchResults" action="{!updateAvailableList}" reRender="searchResults" status="searchStatus"/>

                    <!-- here we invoke the scripting to get out fancy 'no button' search bar to work -->
                    <apex:inputText value="{!searchString}" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13){this.blur();}else{resetTimer();}" style="width:300px"/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <i>
                        <!-- actionStatus component makes it easy to let the user know when a search is underway -->
                        <apex:actionStatus id="searchStatus" startText="searching..." stopText=" "/>
                    </i>

                </apex:actionRegion>

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <apex:outputPanel id="searchResults">

                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!AvailableSites}" var="a">

                        <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!a.Name}" />

                        <apex:column >
                            <!-- command button in a column... neato -->
                            <apex:commandButton value="Select" action="{!addToSelectedSites}" reRender="selected,searchResults" immediate="true">
                                <!-- again we use apex:param to be able to tell the controller which row we are working with -->
                                <apex:param value="{!a.Id}" assignTo="{!toSelect}" name="toSelect"/>
                            </apex:commandButton>
                        </apex:column>

                    </apex:pageBlockTable>

                    <!-- We put up a warning if results exceed 100 rows -->
                    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="fyi" rendered="{!overLimit}">
                        <br/>
                        Your search returned over 100 results, use a more specific search string if you do not see the desired {!$ObjectType.Product2.Label}.
                        <br/>
                    </apex:outputPanel>

                </apex:outputPanel>

            </apex:pageBlock>

        </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:form>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

        var waitTime = 1;


        var countDown = waitTime+1;
        var started = false;

        function resetTimer(){

            countDown=waitTime+1;

            if(started==false){
                started=true;
                runCountDown();
            }
        }

        function runCountDown(){

            countDown--;

            if(countDown<=0){
                fetchResults();
                started=false;
            }
            else{
                window.setTimeout(runCountDown,1000);
            }
        }

    </script>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: I know you copied this code from elsewhere, but you have a `SOQL` injection vulnerability. In `updateAvailableList`, you need to use `'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchString) + '%'`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the way you've defined your constructor and how you get `selectedsites` in it initially. This appears to be causing `selectedSites` not to be `set` in the page.

Currently, you have:

```
public quoteSiteEntryExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    theQuote = [select Id, Name, AccountId from Quote where Id = :controller.getRecord().Id limit 1];
    selectedSites = [select Id, Quote__c, Site__c, Name, Site__r.Name, Remarks_Special_Instructions__c from Associated_Location__c where Quote__c=:theQuote.Id];
}
```

If instead, you created a method called:

```
public static list<associated_Location__c> getselecteSites(Id theQuoteId){
    list<associated_Location__c>selectedSites = [select Id, Quote__c, Site__c, Name, Site__r.Name, Remarks_Special_Instructions__c from Associated_Location__c where Quote__c=:theQuoteId];
    return selectedSites
    // shouldn't be necessary, but you could also explicity set selectedSites here as well
}
```

Your constructor would then look like:

```
public quoteSiteEntryExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    theQuote = [select Id, Name, AccountId from Quote where Id = :controller.getRecord().Id limit 1];
    getselectdSites(theQuote.Id);
}
```

**Edit**

It occurred to me that if you have a quote that's already in context that you're using to seed this page, your syntax for that record may not be correct for handling it with your query. It should be an instance and would look more like the following:

```
this.Quote = [select Id, Name, AccountId from Quote where Id = :controller.getRecord().Id limit 1];
```

If that's the case, your other code should be adjust accordingly.

Comment: Is this to return the selected sites or the sites that are not selected? I am having an issue with the sites that are not selected when I first hit the page. Let me know if I am off base, again, not much of a developer. Thanks!

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question, but you'll need to separate your lists of selected and unselected so that they get sent to your page. I don't see a list of "unselected" that you've queried at all in your controller. Would that be your `AvailableSites`? If so, you don't call your `updateAvailableList` method or anything similar from your constructor to give it a value! That's why it's not being set.